# How to modify column names in Excel spreadsheet using Powersheell?

Tags: excel, powershell

I currently have a PowerShell script that I am able to use to rename the worksheet name from `"abc"` to `"some-value"`. However, how do I change the column names in the first row?

For example, in the example screenshot, I would like to change `Account.Value` to `"Value"`, `Account.Name` to `"Name"`, and `Account.Owner` to `"Owner"`.

How would I do this using PowerShell?

[image: Column Screenshot]

Comment: Could you add your existing code? Thanks.

Comment: Just edit the cell content i.e.`$Sheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = "`Value"`